# How do you do something when the escape key is pressed on an input field, but not on blur events for that input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

For example, consider the [TodoMVC app](http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/#/).

I'm writing my own version of that app. When you double click a todo item, an input field shows up.

[image]

[image]

When that input field blurs, I want to save the changes. But if the user makes changes and then presses <kbd>escape</kbd>, I don't want to save the changes.

The problem is that pressing the <kbd>escape</kbd> key on the input field triggers a blur event. So when I press escape, the function I have that listens for <kbd>escape</kbd> key presses runs... but so does the function that listens for the blur event.

How can I do something when the <kbd>escape</kbd> key is pressed, and not run the blur event function?

---

**views/todo.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',

  className: 'list-group-item',

  template: _.template( $('#todo-template').html() ),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
    this.$el.find('.edit-mode').hide();
    this.$el.find('.remove-todo').hide();
    return this;
  },

  events: {
    'click input[type="checkbox"]': 'check',
    'mouseenter': 'showRemove',
    'mouseleave': 'hideRemove',
    'click .remove-todo': 'remove',
    'dblclick .todo-title': 'showEditMode',
    'keyup input.edit-todo': 'updateOnEnter',
    'blur input.edit-todo': 'closeAndUpdate'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
  },

  check: function(e) {
    this.model.save({
      completed: true
    });
  },

  showRemove: function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.remove-todo').show();
  },

  hideRemove: function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).find('.remove-todo').hide();
  },

  remove: function(e) {
    var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
    this.model.destroy({
      success: function(model) {
        app.todos.remove(model);
        $el.closest('li').remove();
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Unable to remove todo.');
      }
    });
  },

  showEditMode: function(e) {
    var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
    var $editMode = $el.closest('li').find('.edit-mode');
    $el.closest('.view-mode').hide();
    $editMode.show();
    $editMode.find('.edit-todo').focus();
  },

  updateOnEnter: function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      this.closeAndUpdate();
    }
    else if (e.which === 27) {
      this.closeEditMode();
    }
  },

  closeEditMode: function() {
    var $input = this.$el.find('.edit-todo');
    $input.closest('li').find('.view-mode').show();
    $input.closest('.edit-mode').hide();
  },

  closeAndUpdate: function() {
    var self = this;
    var $input = this.$el.find('.edit-todo');
    var newTitle = $input.val();
    if (newTitle !== this.model.get('title')) {
      this.model.save({
        title: newTitle
      }, {
        success: function(model) {
          self.closeEditMode();
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Unable to update todo');
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      this.closeEditMode();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @thomas I just realized - escape doesn't trigger blur by default. It's just that I manually switch to 'view-mode' when escape is pressed, and *that* is what triggers the blur event.

Answer (score 5):

You can set some boolean flag inside `keypress` handler when Esc is pressed, and then check it inside `blur` handler:

```
...
events: {
  ...
  "keypress .edit"  : "keypress",
  "blur .edit"      : "blur"
},
...
close: function() {
  ...
},
blur: function() {
  if (!this.escFlag) this.close();
  this.escFlag = false;
},
keypress: function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) this.escFlag = true;
},
...
```

Comment: How do you know whether or not `updateOnEnter` will always run before `blur`?

Comment: @Adam Zerner Quote from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/): _If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were bound_. So you just have to ensure `keypress` handler is defined prior to `blur`

Comment: Ok. Well your approach works and seems reasonable. I'd like to hear some other ideas first before choosing a best answer though.

Comment: @hindmost That doc excerpt regards a single event (e.g. when you register multiple handlers on a `blur` event. The handlers for different events will fire in the order that the events are dispatched. I don't know whether the order between `keypress` and `blur` is specified, but recently I had no success intercepting `keydown` before `blur`, so it may differ between browsers.